# Value error : Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create' while loading the form using CBV

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a simple form that takes in basic info of school. I created it using 'CreateView' CBV but when I hit the URL, I get the value error: Value error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyVw.png)

Model.py:

```
from django.db import models


class School(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__ (self):
      return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("basic_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Student(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=256)
   age=models.PositiveIntegerField()
   school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View, CreateView
from . import models

class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
   fields=["name","principal","location"]
   model=models.School
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

app_name= 'basic_app'

urlpatterns=[
   path('create/',views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create')
]
```

school_form.html:

```
{% block body_block %}

<h1>
{% if not form.instance.pk %}
Create school:
{% else %}
Update school:
{% endif %}

</h1>

<form  method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value="Submit">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Note:

The URL works if I replace the URL path like 'create/school' (anything added after 'create/)

```
path('create/school',views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create')
```

then the page gets loaded. I could not figure out the issue, can anyone point out the mistake with the previous URL path.

Comment: There is likely another `path` in your `urlpatterns` that has a pattern with `create/` in it?

Comment: No , I do not have any other path like 'create/' in urlpattterns

Comment: For me, I had `event/<pk>` before `event/create` and tried to match "create" as a primary key.  I put the `<pk>` afterwards and it stopped.